# JMeter HTTP Request with "Follow redirect" can get extracted value from response

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter HTTP Request that returns a 302 response with some parameter fields in the redirect URL that I need to extract (ex. state, scope). When I turn off `Follow Redirects` I correctly get the values extracted, but I don't get a cookie that I need for the next request.

Reversely, when I enable `Follow Redirects` for the HTTP Request, I automatically get the cookie for the next request but I don't get parameter fields that I'm extracting from the response. How do I get both?

Answer (score 1):

Add a Regular Expression Extractor and select "Main sample and sub-sample". Now you will be able to extract data from next request that you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use Follow redirect to generate the cookies.And if you are unable to generate the subsequent request in follow redirect. Create separate http request manually with the url and details you gathered from redirect automatically option

Comment: Can you add some punctuation or formatting to this? It's pretty difficult to make sense of without any commas, full stops, or formatting.